# Selectize.js - do something when item is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using selectize.js. I want to do something when a new item is added. When I run this code below, the alert shows up, but the item will not be selected. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('#select-beast').selectize({
        create: true,
        sortField: 'text',
        onItemAdd: function() {
          alert('Do something');
        }

      });
```

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle code version?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yf8r19mh/ - I realize it only is strange when I press Enter o keyboard to adding item. Then the form will be posted. Is there a way to get the form not to post when pressing Enter on Add?

Comment: for preventing form post, just write  <form role="form" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">

Comment: Thank you!! Do you know if it's possible to get the text of the item I added within the alert? Such as alert(value);?

Comment: change to it: onItemAdd: function(text) {
      alert(text);
    }

Comment: Many thanks, @GurgenSargsyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a options model: http://jsfiddle.net/yf8r19mh/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#select-beast').selectize({
    create: true,
    sortField: 'text',
    maxItems: null,
        valueField: 'id',
        labelField: 'text',
    options: [
                        {id: 1, text: 'Chuck Testa'},
                        {id: 2, text: 'Sage Cattabriga-Alosa'},
                        {id: 3, text: 'Nikola Tesla'}
                    ],
    onItemAdd: function() {
      alert('test');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is an option model? Isn't it enough to have the data in html?